# Помогите выбрать курс по c# цена / качество

Tags: c#

Около года изучал c++ и месяца 2 назад решил начать изучать c#. Всё хорошо, казалось бы, но постоянное чувство, что я что-то упускаю, теряю какую то сферу знаний не покидает меня. Потому хочу перейти со скитаний по сайтам и книгам на полноценный курс со систематически организованной и полноценной подачей материала. Я наверняка слепой, раз не смог найти нормальный ответ в интернете по поводу курсов c# на сегодня, потому прошу поделиться опытом в покупке курсов и общее мнение о материале, его доступности и качества курса в целом. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Тут https://ulearn.me/ опубликован неплохой курс от СКБ контур.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты бы уточнил из какого ты города. Я вот в Харькове в АЛевел хожу https://a-level.com.ua/ информации много, но она структурированная  и подается с примерами. Преподаватели реальные разработчики, поэтому помимо сухой информации, могут поделиться и лайфхаками.

Comment: Вот еще, я проходил курс на ITVDN https://itvdn.com/ru/ (базовый и ООП). Очень подробно и хорошо рассказывается. Там есть пробные уроки так что можешь посмотреть. + там есть ДЗ и интерактивный тренажер для выполнения заданий на сайте.

Comment: В перми живу. Я имел в виду именно онлайн курсы.

Comment: Ну вот ITVDN курс мне понравился. Советую. Там еще даются бонусы за заполнение информации о себе и за посещение сайта, можно на бесплатную месячную подписку насобирать.